# Latex Sublime snippet

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext-snippet

I'm using a Sublime snippet to create a Latex state machine template. However, it does nothing (when I type "stmach" and press tab, `stmach` disappears but the Latex code isn't included). I don't understand why, as all my other snippets are working fine.

If I remove some lines in the snippet, it works, but I need the whole block :/

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=4.5cm,on grid,auto]

        \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20] % Node color

        \node[state,initial,initial text=reset, initial where=below] (configuration) {$conf$}; % Node name and position
        \node[state] (init) [below right=of configuration] {$init$};

        \path[->] % Arrow
        (configuration)
            edge  [bend left]                 node {finishConfiguration=1} (init)

        (init)
            edge  [bend left]                 node {} (configuration);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>stmach</tabTrigger> 
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<scope>text.tex</scope>
```

Note that the Latex code works without any error or warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$` character has special meaning in Sublime Text snippets, and therefore needs to be escaped to be valid.

You can escape them with a preceding backslash, as the [documentation shows](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/snippets.html):

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=4.5cm,on grid,auto]

        \tikzstyle{every state}=[draw=blue!50,very thick,fill=blue!20] % Node color

        \node[state,initial,initial text=reset, initial where=below] (configuration) {\$conf\$}; % Node name and position
        \node[state] (init) [below right=of configuration] {\$init\$};

        \path[->] % Arrow
        (configuration)
            edge  [bend left]                 node {finishConfiguration=1} (init)

        (init)
            edge  [bend left]                 node {} (configuration);

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>stmach</tabTrigger> 
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<scope>text.tex</scope>
</snippet>
```

---

Using the syntax highlighting from https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/pull/576 makes the problem clearer, as ST unfortunately doesn't offer any feedback, as you have seen:
[image: invalid snippet]

How it looks when escaped:
[image: valid snippet]