# create PHP text snippet Sublime Text 3

Tags: php, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, code-snippets

```
<snippet>

<content>
  <![CDATA[<?= $item['lorem ipsum']?>]]>
</content>

<tabTrigger>item</tabTrigger>

</snippet>
```

Hello, help me please make a snippet using the **$** - symbol, I need to when spelling an **item** and use the **TAB** - write a full command with sign   , now the $ sign is ignored `<?= ['lorem ipsum']?>`

Comment: Please show us the code you've written and we'll give you help ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latex Sublime snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481224/latex-sublime-snippet)

Answer (score 1):

i find... need use \ with **$**
working snippet

```
<snippet>

<content><![CDATA[
<?= \$item['lorem ipsum']?>
]]></content>

<tabTrigger>item</tabTrigger>
```