# jquery increment input snippet not working in sublime

Tags: jquery, sublimetext3

I have the following jquery snippe:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
/$("[data-increment-input-value='true']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var /$input = /$(this).siblings('input');
    /$input.val(parseInt(/$input.val())+1);
});

/$("[data-decrement-input-value='true']").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var /$input = /$(this).siblings('input');
    /$input.val(parseInt(/$input.val())-1);
});
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>jq-increment-decrement-input</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.js</scope>
</snippet>
```

I have escaped all the doller signs , but i still cant selected the snippet when i am in my JS files . Why ? I mean it shows in the dropdown but then dissapers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latex Sublime snippet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481224/latex-sublime-snippet)

Comment: you need to use a backslash (\) to escape a $ in ST snippets, not a forward slash (/)

Comment: @KeithHall thanks aloot :)