# Sublime text 3 - include $ sign in snippet

Tags: jquery, sublimetext3, sublimetext, code-snippets

How do I include a `$` sign in a snippet for Sublime 3?
The problem here is that Sublime uses `$` sign as its own char for placeholder. But here I need to use it as plaintext in line `var $ = require('jQuery');`
If I'm trying to use this snippet like it shown here, it doesn't work.
Here it is:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[

var React = require('react');
var ReacDOM = require('react-dom');
var expect = require('expect');
var $ = require('jQuery');
var TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');

var $1 = require('$1');

describe('$1', () => {
    it('should exist', () => {
        expect(CountdownForm).toExist();
    });
});

]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>rct</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latex Sublime snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481224/latex-sublime-snippet)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try escaping the `$` with a `\`?
For instance in PHP, the $GLOBALS snippet is:

```
<snippet>
<content><![CDATA[
var React = require('react');
var ReacDOM = require('react-dom');
var expect = require('expect');
var \$ = require('jQuery');
var TestUtils = require('react-addons-test-utils');

var \$1 = require('\$1');

describe('\$1', () => {
it('should exist', () => {
    expect(CountdownForm).toExist();
});
});
]]></content>
<!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
<tabTrigger>debug</tabTrigger>
<!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
<scope>source.php</scope>
</snippet>
```

As you can see, `\` before each dollar sign.

Hope this will help you.

Greetings!

Comment: Have fun @t411tocreate..:)